# What is the mistake in the following BigInteger computation?

Tags: java, algorithm, biginteger

Here is the code I have come up with to compute the sum of all consecutive number between first number i and second number j.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.*;

class Sum {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String s[] = br.readLine().split(" ");
        BigInteger i = new BigInteger(s[0]);
        BigInteger j = new BigInteger(s[1]);
        //I am taking the average of the first number and the last number, and multiplying by the number of numbers i.e. Sum = ((i+j)/2)(j - i)
        BigInteger k = i.add(j);
        BigInteger m = k.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));
        k = m.multiply(j.subtract(i));

        System.out.println(k);
    }
}
```

But for input

**Input**

99 1000000000000

**I am getting the Output**

499999999999499999995149

**Instead of Correct Output**

500000000000499999995149

Where I am wrong?

Comment: I am taking the average of the first number and the last number, and multiplying by the number of numbers.

Comment: You've divided an odd number by 2, so you lost information. Try multiplying first.

Comment: @Solver its known as Gauss formula. multiplying average of two number by their subtract gives you Sigma of those two numbers

Comment: You need to check your input numbers if one was even and one was odd, just add the secound number to the result to compensate the one unit that is going to be rounded during the divide by two. Adding secound number to the result is not just a correction, it makes completely sense.

Answer (score 7):

Your code is correct, the problem is you are inputing an odd and an even number which makes the k in `k = i.add(j)` an odd number that can not be devided by two without truncating!

So m in `BigInteger m = k.divide(BigInteger.valueOf(2));` is being rounded and this makes a 1 unit change in your calculations.

just take a look at the correct answer and compare it with the one your program has printed out. you have a 1 * 1000000000000(second inputed value) bias. Which says the problem itself.

Your program will work and print the correct answer if you input two even or two odd number to it.

I hope this was enough for you to find a way correcting your program in case an even and an odd number is given as input.